# Customized scikit-learns Transformation and ColumnTransformer error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, customization, pipeline

I created the following customized Transformation to Winsorize/clip my dataset based on a given lower and upper quantiles

```
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted, check_array

class OutlierExtractor(TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, limits=[None, None]):
        self.limits_ = limits

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        X = check_array(X, copy=self.copy, force_all_finite=False, ensure_2d=False)
        if self.limits_[0] is not None:
            self.a_min_ = np.quantile(X, self.limits_[0], axis=0)
            
        if self.limits_[1] is not None:
            self.a_max_ = np.quantile(X, self.limits_[1], axis=0)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        print('transform')
        check_is_fitted(self, ["a_max_", "a_min_"])
        X = check_array(X, copy=self.copy, force_all_finite=False, ensure_2d=False)
        return np.clip(X, self.a_min_, self.a_max_)
```

when calling the `ColumnTransformer` I get the following error message which indicate that the pipeline is not fitted

```
preprocess_pipeline = ColumnTransformer(
                transformers= [
                    ('ABC', 
                    OutlierExtractor(limits=[0.01, 0.99]) , 
                 ['Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3'])
                         ]
                    , remainder='passthrough'
                )
preprocess_pipeline.fit(df_trn)
```

Error Message:

> NotFittedError: This OutlierExtractor instance is not fitted yet. Call
> 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.

I am unable to determine why the *limits* values provided in the `ColumnTransformer` function are not used.

**Update:**

I think I was able to figure out the problem. A `get_params` function was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to figure out the problem. A `get_params` function was missing.